# Ember.js - assertion failed: calling set on destroyed object

Tags: ember.js

Hello my EmberJS Router code like this but when i want change the `{{outlet}}` use `{{action showIntor href=true}}` and `{{action showDemo href=true}}` the console is loging:

> assertion failed: calling set on destroyed object

how can i fixed it?

Here's my code:

```
define('app/router',[
    'lib/ember'
],
function() {
    return Ember.Router.extend({
        enableLogging: true,
        root:Ember.Route.extend({
            showIntor:Ember.Route.transitionTo('index'),
            showDemo:Ember.Route.transitionTo('demo'),
            index: Ember.Route.extend({
                route:'/',
                connectOutlets:function(router) {
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('intro')
                }
            }),
            demo:Ember.Route.extend({
                route:'/demo',
                connectOutlets:function(router) {
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('mainDemo')
                }
            })
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show your template script